# pygeoip vs django.contrib.gis.geoip

Tags: python, django, geoip

I'm building a django powered website and need access to the (rough) location of my users and i soon found the free databases from MaxiMind. But i found two ways of accessing them https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/ and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoip/ is one better then the other.

I have not (consciously) used c dependencies in python before...